# OpenGL texture not following geometry

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm struggling with the jump in complexity from OpenGL ES 1.x to 2.0. I'm trying to apply a texture to a rectangular plane and then be able to scale and translate that plane while keeping the texture properly mapped.

My question is: what am I doing wrong and how will I be able to texture my planes while translating and scaling them?

I will post my renderer class, the class that objects will use to draw themselves, and my vertex and fragment shaders:

GL Renderer:

```
package com.detour.raw;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class GameRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

private static final String TAG = "GameRenderer";
Context mContext;
Bitmap bitmap;

private float red = 0.5f;
private float green = 0.5f;
private float blue = 0.5f;

Shader shader;
int program;
FPSCounter fps;
Sprite sprite;
Sprite sprite2;
int x = 0;

private int muMVPMatrixHandle;

private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];
//private float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
//private float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];
//private float[] mVPMatrix = new float[16];
//private float[] mIMatrix = new float[16];



public GameRenderer(Context context){
    mContext = context;

    //create objects/sprites
    sprite = new Sprite(mContext);
    sprite2 = new Sprite(mContext);
    fps = new FPSCounter();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(red, green, blue, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    //Matrix.setIdentityM(mIMatrix, 0);

    //Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix , 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    sprite.draw();
    /*if(x>3){
        x=0;
    }
    if(x%2==0){
        sprite.draw();
    }else{
        sprite2.draw();
    }
    x++;*/

    //fps.calculate();
    //fps.draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = ((float)(width))/((float)(height));
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 0.5f, 10);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mMVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*int error = GLES20.glGetError();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, ""+error);*/

    shader = new Shader(R.raw.sprite_vs, R.raw.sprite_fs, mContext);
    program = shader.getProgram();

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_MVPMatrix");

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
    GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
    GLES20.glClearColor(red, green, blue, 1.0f);


    sprite.loadGLTexture(R.drawable.raw1a, program);
    sprite2.loadGLTexture(R.drawable.raw2, program);

    System.gc();
}

}
```

Drawable class:

```
package com.detour.raw;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

public class RenderVisible implements Renderable{

Context mContext;
Bitmap bitmap;

private int vertexHandle;
private int texCoordHandle;
private int textureHandle;

private int[] textures = new int[1];

private float textureCoordinates[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
        };

private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f,// 0.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,// 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,// 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f// 0.0f,
         };

private short[] indices = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3};

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;


public RenderVisible(Context context){

    mContext = context;

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoordinates.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(textureCoordinates);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);

}

@Override
public void draw() {

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

}

@Override
public void loadGLTexture(int id, int program) {

    vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
    texCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");
    textureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id);
    /*InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }*/

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

    //GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuf);//(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0) * u_MVPMatrix;
    v_texcoord = a_position * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

When I run the program like this, I get my expected result:

[image]

When I change the vertices of my renderable (in this case all divided each value by 2), the shape of my plane changes but the texture doesn't move with it the way I would expect. I'm not sure why (an explanation would be nice).

[image]

When I fix the vertices of my plane and change the vertex shader to accept the texture coordinates I give it (`v_texcoord = a_texcoord;`), I get the correct size square but the texture isn't visible/the square is completely white.

I am also attempting to make methods for the renderable (RenderVisible) class that would make it simple to move and scale my sprites.  How might I do that?

Comment: What happens if you don't calculate the texture-coords in the vertex program but use the ones that you specify in the java code? (In the vertex program: v_texcoord = a_texcoord;)

Comment: I get the correct size square but the texture isn't visible/the square is completely white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are a function of your vertex coordinates, that is the why of this behaviour, to fix it, just change in your vertex shader:

```
v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
```

So you use your constant texture coordinates. Also remember to enable the texture coord vertex attribute:

```
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);
```

Comment: I mentioned this at the end of my question. When I try that, I get the correct size rectangle, but it is completely white, no texture.

Comment: @Amplify91 See the updated answer, you didn't enable the texcoord attrib.

Comment: UGH! Thank you! I knew it had to be some minuscule, stupid mistake. What is your suggestion for how to translate and scale sprites?